# Getting FilePaths to work correctly in Batch (writing to a text file)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm iterating through about 300 directories and trying to create a text file in each. All of my code works except for file creation and subsequent writing. Here's how I'm attempting the write to file: (I should note that this code is within a nested for loop using setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion)

```
if !q! == 0 (
    set myString=%%f
    set myString=!myString:~0,-12!\temporary.txt        
    echo !m! >> !myString!
)
```

where %%f is the path to another text file I'm doing an analysis on, so I have to shorten the path. The name of this text file is uniform across all directories. I have tried just using:

```
echo !myString!
```

which produces an example output of (correct file-path):

```
C:\mywork2\MAX\BOTH0\temporary.txt
```

However, when I run the complete code block above I receive:

```
The fimename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

If I use:

```
if !q! == 0 (
    set myString=%%f    
    echo !m! >> !myString:~0,-12!\temporary.txt
)
```

The program runs without error, but a text file is never created. The text file IS created, however, if I manually type the path (not possible for iteration). What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is the directory layout: C:\mywork2\MAX\ (arbitrary_name) \ dataSet.txt || and C:\mywork2\Trees_Orig\ (phylogenetic trees).

Example data sets (from phylogenetic tree):

```
#NEXUS
begin taxa;
    dimensions ntax=5020;
    taxlabels
    Tachyglossus_aculeatus
    Zaglossus_bruijni
    Zaglossus_bartoni
    Ornithorhynchus_anatinus
    Anomalurus_derbianus
    Anomalurus_beecrofti
    Anomalurus_pelii
    Anomalurus_pusillus
    Microtus_townsendii     
    Peromyscus_californicus
    Odocoileus_hemionus
    Canis_latrans
    Canis_lupus
    Urocyon_cinereoargenteus
    Vulpes_vulpes
    Lynx_lynx
    Euchoreutes_naso
    Jaculus_blanfordi
    Jaculus_jaculus
    Jaculus_orientalis
    Stylodipus_andrewsi
    Stylodipus_sungorus
    Monodelphis_iheringi
```

Example data sets (from dataSet.txt):

```
Species 
Microtus_townsendii     
Peromyscus_californicus     
Odocoileus_hemionus     
Canis_latrans       
Canis_lupus     
Urocyon_cinereoargenteus        
Vulpes_vulpes       
Lynx_lynx       
Puma_concolor       
Gulo_gulo       
Mephitis_mephitis
```

---

Variable names:

```
k: is used to simulate an array, by serving as the indexes to each species in dataSet.txt
f: is a dataSet.txt from C:\mywork2\MAX\*
i: represents the first tab delimited term of each dataSet.txt row (I've truncated this for you)
g: is a .tre phylogenetic tree (there's 2), but I have truncated it's length due to example
j: represents the first term of each row within the phylogenetic tree

q: serves as a boolean variable which is 1 when a species from the phylogenetic tree
   is also in the dataSet.txt file. Otherwise 0.
n: serves as a boolean variable to tell when the batch file is examining species from the
   phylogenetic tree and not meta data.

m: is the index of each species within the phylogenetic tree. These are written to a text file
   when q = 0. This is because I will be creating a Paup block within a .NEX file to remove all
   species within the phylogenetic tree not present in dataSet.txt.

myString: this variable is used to hold a truncated file path. I want each temporary.txt file to
          be in the same directory as its respective dataSet.txt file.
```

---

Edit: Here is my code -->

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "TabChar=   "

for /r C:\mywork2\MAX\ %%f in (*) do (
    set k=0
    for /f "delims=%TabChar%" %%i in (%%f) do ( 
        if NOT %%i == Species (
            set /A k+=1
            set elem[!k!]=%%i
        )
    )

    for /r C:\mywork2\Trees_Orig\ %%g in (*) do (
        set m=0
        set n=0

        for /f %%j in (%%g) do (
            set q=0

            if !n! == 1 (
                set /A m+=1
                for /L %%i in (1,1,!k!) do (
                    if !elem[%%i]! == %%j (
                        set q=1
                    )
                )

                if !q! == 0 (
                    set myString=%%f    
                    echo !m! >> !myString:~0,-12!\temporary.txt
                )
            )

            if %%j == taxlabels (
                set n=1
            )

            if %%j == Monodelphis_iheringi (
                set n=0
            )

        )

        PAUSE
    )
)

PAUSE
```

Comment: Please post sufficient of your code to allow reproduction of the problem on others' machines. Include a representative subtree listing and sufficient detail of the variables' purposes to allow analysis.

Comment: Working on the variables now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's sufficient of the Yuletide spirit left for me to respond.

`n` and `q` are being used as flags. Better named as *purpose*flag to remove requirement to refer to documentation. Whereas setting the flags to 1/0 and using delayedexpansion to access their dynamic values will work, a better scheme is to set them to *nothing* or *something* then use `if defined flagvalue` which works whether delayedexpansion is invoked or not.

`m` and `k` are counter values, better named as *purpose*counter then there's no need for documentation.

`mystring` is another meaningless variable name. Better named `destinationdirectory` to document the purpose. There's no point in setting this variable where you are doing it - it depends solely on `%%f` so setting it at the start of the `for %%f` block means that it will only be set once for each `%%f` not each time the inner loop is executed (on the data provided, once against 15 times.)

The value assigned to `mystring` also appears unstable - relying on the length of the filename in `%%f`. Since you're simply selecting drive and path, `%%~dpf` is a better choice.

If you surround the destination filename with quotes, the process creates the destination file as apparently expected **but** since this is another file in the same directory as is being scanned by `%%f` then the filename `temporary.txt` will appear in that directory  and your process will attempt to use that file as as a datasource, attempting to create `dirname\t\temporary.txt` and this directory does not exist (the `t` comes from `dirname\temporary.txt` processed by the substring to position `-12`. Using `%%~dpf` would cure that problem (but not the scanning of files created by this process)

To skip the scanning of the `temporary.txt` files, you could either add `if /i "%%~nxf" neq "temporary.txt"` as a gate after the `for ... %%f...do` or use a `dir/s/b` scan of the required directory as a list to source `%%f` since the list would be fully generated before the processing takes place, so excludes files generated within the process.

The results I obtained from the supplied data were 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 but you've not posted expected results, so I've no idea whether that result is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I can't wait to read up on %%~dpf, %%~nxf, and scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Some injections only:

- Omit `"delims=%TabChar%"`, as any of the following are always valid delimiters: *Comma* `,`, *Semicolon* `;`, *Equals* `=`, *Space*  and *Tab*
- Comparison with `==` is always *textual*; therefore omit all `==` surrounding spaces; for best end, surround compared strings with e.g. quotes as follows: `if NOT "%%i"=="Species" (` ...
- Instead of redirecting echo to a file downright, try `echo !m! ^>^> !myString:~0,-12!\temporary.txt` to see all command *as is*